# VSTS ARM Service Endpoint for national cloud environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to create a Release Definition from my VSTS instance in west Europe to deploy an App in the Azure German Cloud. I tried creating an ARM Service Endpoint but it seems it tried to use by default the service management management.core.windows.net and the endpoint in Germany.

I've also tried using an Azure classic but I keep getting an authentication error: There was an error with the Azure credentials used for the deployment....the user I am using for that has owner role in my subscription. Besides Azure Classic Service Endpoint are deprecated.

1. Is there any way to change the environment endpoints for the Service Endpoint.
2. Any restrictions trying to deploy to the German cloud from a VSTS instance in west Europe?

Comment: How do you configure ARM Service endpoint, with Subscription (Detected automatically) or Subscription ID, name etc (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/girishp/2016/04/24/creating-an-arm-service-deployment-endpoint-in-vsts/)? How do you it uses default service management and endpoint in Germany?

Comment: Since VSTS is not yet available in Germany I have my VSTS instance linked to another Azure AD in WestEurope. That why I need to specify the Azure Environment so that VSTS tries to authenticate against the right endpoint (...cloudapi.de)

Comment: How do you configure ARM Service endpoint?